SwiftUI double toolbar
I'm experiencing an issue with duplicate toolbars in my application. The code seems to work, but it creates a double toolbar at the top of the modal for some reason. The following code creates a modal dialog for updating a list of locations:
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct XMarkButton: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: "xmark") //changed to image, can change color here if needed
            .font(.headline)
    }
}

struct SettingsView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    @Query private var locations: [Location]

    @State private var showCreate = false

    var body: some View {

        NavigationSplitView {
            List {
                ForEach(locations) { location in
                    HStack {
                        Text(location.name)
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                            .bold()
                    }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteLocations)
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    XMarkButton().onTapGesture { // on tap gesture calls dismissal
                        dismiss()
                    }
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    EditButton()
                }
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button(action: {
                        showCreate.toggle()
                    }, label: {
                        Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                    })
                }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showCreate,
                   content: {
                NavigationStack {
                    CreateLocationView()
                }
                .presentationDetents([.large])
            })
        } detail: {
            Text("Select a location")
        }
    }

    private func addLocation() {
        withAnimation {
            let newLocation = Location()
            modelContext.insert(newLocation)
        }
    }

    private func deleteLocations(offsets: IndexSet) {
        withAnimation {
            for index in offsets {
                modelContext.delete(locations[index])
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    SettingsView()
}

Here is a screenshot so that you can see what I mean:

Could you provide guidance or suggestions on how to prevent or resolve this problem? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

I can't reproduce with the given code. Make sure what you have posted is enough code for someone else to reproduce the issue.

Somehow you are nesting navigation views. This settings screen is somehow inside a navigation stack, Split View, etc

To troubleshoot and try to identify which toolbar comes from a specific view, you can try printing something to the console inside one of the toolbar items or consider adding something like a .border(.red) to have a visual indication.

@loremipsum you are correct, I am nesting it in a NavigationSplitView ... I will look for a way to fix this. If you present this as an answer I will accept it.

You have 2 navigation bars because you are somehow nesting Navigation
NavigationSplitView
    NavigationStack

Is a common example
